# Why we can rewrite $f(x) = 0$ to $x = g(x)$ in fixed point iteration method?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I've been looking for explanations on the internet about the fixed-point iteration method. But all of them just giving the same thing that I haven't understand, which is

We can rewrite the equation $$f(x)=0$$ to $$x=g(x)$$

I know this might be very dumb to ask but it's fine since I've been stuck on this but please help me on this.

Comment: I know nothing about this, but can't you just add $x$ on both sides, and define $g(x)=f(x) + x$?

Comment: Isn't choosing $g(x)=f(x)+x$ would always work? @kingW3

Comment: Actually, I'm also confused about how to connect this to the theorem

Comment: I don't think $g(x) $ will converge most of the time, or even if such $g$ exists at all that will converge to the fixed point, I think the assumption is that if you can find such $g$ it's bound to converge assuming some properties.

Comment: If $f(a)=0$ and $f$ is continuous in $(a-b;a+b)$, $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x\neq a$, $x\in(a-b;a+b)$, then one can find $c\leq b$ and function $g(x)$ such that $g(a)=a$ and iterative process $x_i=g(x_{i-1})$ converges to $a$ for any $x_0\in(a-c;a+c)$. Algorithm of finding such function is not universal for any $f(x)$. Example $g(x)=x+f(x)$ is only example of existence of function, allowing $g(a)=a$. Better option is $g(x)=x+kf(x)$ with search of real parameter $k$ such that iterative process converges.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks it much clearer now, but why is $x_0$ from $(a-c;a+c)$. I mean why not from $(a-b,a+b)$

Comment: $f(x)$ may be highly-nonmonotonous in $(a-b;a+b)$ so maybe it's better to search root in narrower interval.